# Swift UIFont not changing UICollectionView's reusable cell's size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have this code for changing the size of the reusable cell in a UICollectionView but the size isn't changing and I'm not sure why... any ideas?

```
headerLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue-Bold", size:50.0)
```

Comment: Why do you think changing the font size will change the size of the cell?

Comment: I meant the font size of the reusable cell...